# have different socket.defaulttimeout for different threads?

Tags: python, sockets

I use the `socket.setdefaulttimeout(X)` to set the time out for `X` seconds.  I have two threads (one main thread and another thread) in the main thread I want the socket timeout to be `5` seconds but for the thread I want it to be `0.5` seconds.

Whenever any of these threads changes the timeout, it affects the timeout for the whole program, is there any way to have different socket timeout for different threads in python ?

Comment: no. set the timeout manually on each socket.

Comment: As @mata said, you can set the timeout for each socket by calling `socketA.settimeout(...)`, `socketB.settimeout(...)`, ...

Comment: but I dont make any instances of the socket, I have one default socket, that urllib uses it to open urls...can I make urllib to uses a specific socket?

Comment: If you're planning On having multiple threads read the same socket I *strongly* advise you to reconsider your design. This is not going to work.

Comment: but how can I make two different urlib,FancyURLopener in two different threads to use two different sockets is there any way to pass a socket to a URLopener?